# Update Meta Value for WordPress posts with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to update the meta value for all of my posts in a WordPress database that match a certain criteria.

I have a table I created called `update_with_false` where each row "value" matches the `post_name` of a post in the `wp_posts` table.

What I need to do is change the `meta_value` for the `meta_key` "included_in_related_articles" to "true" for each post in the `wp_posts` table that has the same post name as the rows in the update_with_false table.

Here is my SQL right now, but I'm getting a syntax error:

```
UPDATE SET wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
select ID, 'included_in_related_articles', 'true' from wp_posts
WHERE update_with_false.value = wp_posts.post_name
```

Hopefully that makes sense. I've attached a couple of screenshots of the meta fields I need to update and of the extra table I created

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to update *wp_postmeta.meta_value* and set it to **true** if the value in *wp_posts.post_name* is found in *update_with_false.value*.

You can do this by first joining *wp_posts.post_name* column to the *wp_postmeta* table and then limiting the joined posts by further joining *update_with_false* table.

I'm writing this off the top of my head (with a little help from this
[ER diagram](https://codex.wordpress.org/images/2/25/WP4.4.2-ERD.png)):

```
update wp_postmeta pm
  inner join wp_posts p on p.id = pm.post_id
    inner join update_with_false x on x.value = p.post_name
set pm.meta_value = 'true'
where pm.meta_key = 'included_in_related_articles'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but what I need is for it to update only posts with the "included_in_related_articles" meta key.  Not for all posts.

Comment: See the updated version. I've added the "meta_key" condition.

Comment: Thanks for the update, this appears to work but only for 100ish of the posts out of 300.  I think it's probably something happening on my server to prevent the full amount from being processed so I'll mark this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using sub query as follows :

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value`= 'true' WHERE meta_key = 'included_in_related_articles' AND `post_id` IN (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts AS wps LEFT JOIN update_with_false AS uwf on (wps.post_name = uwf.value) )
```

Where `SELECT ID FROM wp_posts AS wps LEFT JOIN update_with_false AS uwf on (wps.post_name = uwf.value)` is sub query, will give comma separated IDs from wp_posts table.